# Was this possible in Python before [any previous version]

Tags: python, list, slice, deprecated

I remember vaguely that this thing was working a long time ago
Does anybody know that if this code really worked before?
and if this was deprecated since any newer python version?

**code**

```
# My python version is 3.8

lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
lst[0:3] = 100
print(lst)
```

**current output**

```
TypeError: can only assign an iterable
```

**expected output**

```
[100, 'd']
```

Thanks

Comment: Must've been very long ago. Why are you asking?

Comment: this is `numpy` syntax, that's where this sort of thing works (not exactly though - output would be similar to `[100, 100, 100, 'd']`)

Comment: Maybe you mean `lst[0:3] = 100,`?

Comment: This *never* worked with plain python lists. Maybe what you saw was `lst[0:3] = [100]`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**This doesn't work in any version because slicing assignment requires a sequence-like object to assign as.**

The reason it doesn't work is because you need to convert it to a single itemed sequence, like the below:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
lst[:3] = [100]
print(lst)
```

Or with a tuple:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
lst[:3] = 100,
print(lst)
```

Since `lst[:3]` gives an sequence object, the object you assign it to also needs to be a sequence object.

This wouldn't possible in any version in python... For indexing not using a single itemed sequence would be the only way. Like this:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
lst[3] = 100
print(lst)
```

But for slicing sequences would be required for all python versions.

## As mentioned in the [documentation for python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements), [documentation of python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements):

> The length of the slice may be different from the length of the assigned sequence, thus changing the length of the target sequence, if the target sequence allows it.

## As I see in the documentation of [Python 1.4](https://docs.python.org/release/1.4/ref/ref6.html#HDR2):

> If the target is a slicing: The primary expression in the reference is evaluated. It should yield a mutable sequence object (e.g. a list). The assigned object should be a sequence object of the same type.

This documentation was released in 1996.

So for 25 years, this couldn't be possible, python docs was in 1996, but actually python 1 started in 1994.

All version documentation references are the same.

Answer (score 6):

For Python's own built in type this has not been possible before, at least in the past 20 years and more.

> ##### [Assignment Statements](https://docs.python.org/release/1.4/ref/ref6.html#HDR2)
>
> If the target is a slicing: The primary expression in the reference is evaluated. It should yield a mutable sequence object (e.g. a list). *The assigned object should be a sequence object of the same type.* […]
>
> -- Python 1.4, documentation released on 25 October 1996.

The same statement is present in [all published documentation](https://www.python.org/doc/versions/) up to the current version.

---

Note that as per the data model, *semantically* Python does not have such a restriction.

> ##### [Data Model: Emulating sequence and mapping types](https://docs.python.org/release/1.4/ref/ref3.html#HDR4)
>
> `__setslice__(self, i, j, sequence)` Called to implement assignment to `self[i:j]`. *The sequence argument can have any type.* The return value should be `None`. Same notes for `i` and `j` as for `__getslice__`.
>
> -- Python 1.4, documentation released on 25 October 1996.

Custom types, most prominently `numpy.array`, are free to interpret slice assignment of scalars as they please.